# Usar dos puntos como valor de atributo en XML

Tags: xml, atributos

Estoy trabajando en XML con el programa Oxygen. Concretamente, se trata de registrar una edición sobre un texto original. Cada palabra (token) es editada de acuerdo con unas normas y esto incluye también signos de puntuación editados. Por ejemplo, una coma es editada a dos puntos. Mi problema surge en el momento de registrar esa edición pues no puedo usar los dos puntos (:) como valor de un atributo, así:

```
<pc change=":">,</pc>
```

Oxygen me recuerda que el valor del atributo es inválido y que debe ser un URI. He intentado escapar el caracter:

```
<pc change="&#58;">,</pc>
```

pero el programa me sigue dando error. ¿Existe alguna forma de usar los dos puntos como valor de un atributo en XML?

Answer (score 0):

Creo que estás confundiendo entidades HTML con caracteres *escapados* en direcciones URI, prueba con `%3A` en lugar de `&#58;`

De todos modos, sin saber el DTD o XSD que usas para validad ese XML, sintácticamente es válido usar `:` como valor de un atributo, así que quizá el titulo de la pregunta no es del todo correcto.